# Windows phone 7.1 can I change font size on a shell tile?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to display a tweet on the backside of a live tile, when I set it as BackContent it's way too big.... Is there any way to lower the font size?

EDIT:

Claus, Now i'm having trouble getting the tile to display and I can't get any info on why it's not working due to the nature of your ImageOpened call, I can't step through it with the debugger....

In my TileGenerator class, this works:

```
    public static void GenerateTestTile(string strTweet, string strScreenName, string tileTitle)
    {


            // Define the tile's address. This is where you navigate, when the tile is clicked.
            var address = "/MainPage.xaml?TileID=6";

            // Check if a tile with the same address already exists
            //var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString() == address);
            var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            // Define our tile data.
            var tileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackTitle = strScreenName,
                BackContent = strTweet
            };

            // If the file already exists, update it.
            if (tile != null)
            {
                tile.Update(tileData);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, create a new tile. 
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri(address, UriKind.Relative), tileData);
            }

    }
```

But this doesn't (exact method taken from your example), it doesn't do anything to the tile at all...

```
    public static void GenerateExampleTile(string timeOfDay, string temperature, Uri cloudImagePath, string tileTitle)
    {
        // Setup the font style for our tile.
        var fontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe WP");
        var fontForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        var tileSize = new Size(173, 173);

        // Create a background rectagle for a custom colour background.
        var backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle();
        backgroundRectangle.Width = tileSize.Width;
        backgroundRectangle.Height = tileSize.Height;
        backgroundRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        // Load our 'cloud' image.
        var source = new BitmapImage(cloudImagePath);
        source.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        source.ImageOpened += (sender, e) => // This is important. The image can't be rendered before it's loaded.
        {
            // Create our image as a control, so it can be rendered to the WriteableBitmap.
            var cloudImage = new Image();
            cloudImage.Source = source;
            cloudImage.Width = 100;
            cloudImage.Height = 64;

            // TextBlock for the time of the day.
            TextBlock timeOfDayTextBlock = new TextBlock();
            timeOfDayTextBlock.Text = timeOfDay;
            timeOfDayTextBlock.FontSize = 20;
            timeOfDayTextBlock.Foreground = fontForeground;
            timeOfDayTextBlock.FontFamily = fontFamily;

            // Temperature TextBlock.
            TextBlock temperatureTextBlock = new TextBlock();
            temperatureTextBlock.Text = temperature + '°';
            temperatureTextBlock.FontSize = 30;
            temperatureTextBlock.Foreground = fontForeground;
            temperatureTextBlock.FontFamily = fontFamily;

            // Define the filename for our tile. Take note that a tile image *must* be saved in /Shared/ShellContent
            // or otherwise it won't display.
            var tileImage = string.Format("/Shared/ShellContent/{0}.jpg", timeOfDay);

            // Define the path to the isolatedstorage, so we can load our generated tile from there.
            var isoStoreTileImage = string.Format("isostore:{0}", tileImage);

            // Open the ISF store, 
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                // Create our bitmap, in our selected dimension.
                var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)tileSize.Width, (int)tileSize.Height);

                // Render our background. Remember the renders are in the same order as XAML,
                // so whatever is rendered first, is rendered behind the next element.
                bitmap.Render(backgroundRectangle, new TranslateTransform());

                // Render our cloud image
                bitmap.Render(cloudImage, new TranslateTransform()
                {
                    X = 8, // Left margin offset.
                    Y = 54 // Top margin offset.
                });

                // Render the temperature text.
                bitmap.Render(temperatureTextBlock, new TranslateTransform()
                {
                    X = 124,
                    Y = 63
                });

                // Render the time of the day text.
                bitmap.Render(timeOfDayTextBlock, new TranslateTransform()
                {
                    X = 12,
                    Y = 6
                });

                // Create a stream to store our file in.
                var stream = store.CreateFile(tileImage);

                // Invalidate the bitmap to make it actually render.
                bitmap.Invalidate();

                // Save it to our stream.
                bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, 173, 173, 0, 100);

                // Close the stream, and by that saving the file to the ISF.
                stream.Close();
            }

            // Define the tile's address. This is where you navigate, when the tile is clicked.
            var address = "/MainPage.xaml?TileID=" + timeOfDay;

            // Check if a tile with the same address already exists
            var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString() == address);

            // Define our tile data.
            var tileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri(isoStoreTileImage, UriKind.Absolute),
                Title = tileTitle,
            };

            // If the file already exists, update it.
            if (tile != null)
            {
                tile.Update(tileData);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, create a new tile. 
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri(address, UriKind.Relative), tileData);
            }
        };
    }
```

Both methods are being called in this way....

public class ScheduledAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
    {

```
    ...


    /// <summary>
    /// Agent that runs a scheduled task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">
    /// The invoked task
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method is called when a periodic or resource intensive task is invoked
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        LoadWatchList();

    }

    //WATCH LIST
    private void LoadWatchList()
    {
        if (HasConnectivity)
        {
            GetWatchListTweetsFromTwitter(CurrentWatchListID);
        }

    }

    public void GetWatchListTweetsFromTwitter(int list_id)
    {
        WebClient wcWatchListTimeline = new WebClient();
        wcWatchListTimeline.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wcWatchListTimeline_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wcWatchListTimeline.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.xml?per_page=1&list_id=" + list_id));
    }

    void wcWatchListTimeline_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        String strTweet = "content";
        String strScreenName = "title";

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            strScreenName = "error";
            strTweet = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            XElement tweet = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            Tweet thisTweet = GetTweet(tweet);
            if (thisTweet != null)
            {
                strTweet = thisTweet.text;
                strScreenName = thisTweet.screen_name;
            }
        }


        // TAKEN FROM EXAMPLE FOR TESTING - NOT WORKING
        string timeOfday = "morning";
        string temperature = "99";
        string location = "San Antonio";
        Uri cloudImagePath = new Uri("Images/tweetEmpty.png", UriKind.Relative);
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TileGenerator.GenerateExampleTile(timeOfday, temperature, cloudImagePath, "mainTile"));


        //WORKING
        //Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TileGenerator.GenerateTile(strTweet, strScreenName, "mainTile"));

        NotifyComplete();
    }

    protected Tweet GetTweet(XElement Xdata)
    {

        List<Tweet> listTweets = (from tweet in Xdata.Descendants("status")
                                  select new Tweet
                                  {
                                      screen_name = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value,
                                      text = tweet.Element("text").Value
                                  }).ToList<Tweet>();
        if (listTweets.Count > 0)
        {
            return listTweets[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Be careful here.  You don't guarantee that you call NotifyComplete() on all code paths, which will eventually lead to your action becoming unscheduled.

Also, you're not allowed to create a tile from a background agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only by creating a custom image, and using that as the background for the tile.

Updated: [How To: Live Tile with Scheduled Agent](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-live-tile-with-scheduled-agent)

Comment: The tweets are dynamic, not static.

Comment: And? My weather data is also dynamic.

Comment: So the 140 character tweet would be created as an image each time??

Comment: OK, I'm seeing it now, you add textblocks into a bitmap...interesting!  I'll check it out.  Marked as answer for now! :)

Comment: been combing through your app, my situation puts another wrinkle in this since it's a live tiles agent and not in the main app.  Gonna keep plugging away and try to figure this out.

Comment: Trying to add the GenerateTile method to my taskscheduler.cs file and it's giving me a "Invalid cross-thread access." error for this line

var fontForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

very strange.

Comment: Not at all strange, you need to run the tile generation on the UI thread ;-) Use `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: But it's a scheduled event, the UI won't be running to create the tile?  I'm sorry if I'm being super dumb here, just not getting it....

Comment: A scheduled event also have a UI thread. I don't know why, I just know it does.

Comment: Problem has been updated, still unsolved.  Can't get the tile to generate and can't debug.  Check out updated problem above with code...bounty offered...

Comment: Two problems: First, if `HasConnectivity` is false, the ScheduledAgent stops running. And secondly, are you 100% sure it completes within 15 seconds? Ie. have you attached a debugger and checked if it reaches the generation code?

Comment: Claus is back!!!  

So the last point it hits is 

    source.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

VS won't let me debug past that point.

Comment: Right, so it means the `ImageOpened` event is never triggered. That would be because the image Uri is invalid.

Comment: If you try and debug your own project, you'll notice that ImageOpened is not debuggable either.  It never gets hit, but it still works.  The breakpoint doesn't get loaded.  How do I determine if my bitmap image is being created correctly?  Is it possible to load an image from the separate Scheduled Task Agent project?  This test image is now in the root of the STA project... in the tilegenerator the source.UriSource is {tweetEmpty.png}

Comment: Everything that's actually called can be debugged. And the image needs to be in the Application project, not in the STA project! And with a build-action set to `Content`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3708/discussion-between-jarrette-and-claus-jorgensen)

Comment: Should the line `var stream = store.CreateFile(tileImage);` actually be `var stream = store.CreateFile(isoStoreTileImage);`? Otherwise, the `isoStoreTileImage` variable never gets used.

Comment: No. One is the filename for creating a stream, the other is the actual path for the ShellTile. They're not the same.

Comment: still stuck, Claus, I tried using TPL like you suggested, but when I did I had to take out the dispatcher call so I get the cross thread error.  combining the Task logic and the dispatcher logic doesn't work either...

Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => InvokeTileGenerator(strTweet, strScreenName, "mainTile"));
} 
protected void InvokeTileGenerator(string strTweet, string strScreenName, string strTileTitle) 
{ 
Task taskA = new Task(() => TileGenerator.GenerateTile(strTweet, strScreenName, strTileTitle));
Task taskB = taskA.ContinueWith(x => NotifyComplete());
taskA.Start();}

Comment: Updated with a new article that uses a ScheduledAgent, with a full working example.

Comment: github download links are broken, hrmm.

Comment: So it seems. Here's a temporary download: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/TwitterLiveTile.zip